# Wordpress Ajax returning full html of same page

Tags: ajax, wordpress, woocommerce, admin-ajax

Am trying to run Ajax call in my Woocommerce checkout page, but am always getting the full html of same page return.

```
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_scripts' );
function theme_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'theme_scripts', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/assets/js/theme.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'theme_scripts', 'my_ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );  
}
```

Am calling the ajax when address is changed

```
add_action('wp_footer','my_custom_ajax');
function my_custom_ajax(){
?>
<script>
        (function($){
   $( document.body ).on( 'updated_checkout', function(){
        $.ajax({
                url: my_ajax_object.ajaxurl,
                data: {
                    'action':'example_ajax_request',
                },
                success:function(data) {
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            }); 
    });
})(jQuery); 
</script>
<?php
}
```

The example Function

```
  function example_ajax_request() {
echo 'ok';
         wp_send_json_success( 'It works' );
die();
    }

add_action( 'wp_ajax_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_example_ajax_request', 'example_ajax_request' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by using 'nonce'

refer to this [sample project](https://github.com/zgordon/wordpress-ajax)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).